# How do I get a reference to all classes implementing descriptor object in python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am creating a descriptor, and I want to create a list inside it that holds references to all objects implementing it, it is supposed to be some kind of a shortcut where I can call the method on the next instance in line from the instances.

The only daft solution I could find is just on `__init__` of each objects trigger the setter on descriptor that adds the item to the list, even though that solution does work indeed, I can sense that something is wrong with it.

Does anyone have a better way of adding the class instance to a descriptor list other than setting arbitrary value on `__init__`, just to trigger the setter?

```
class GetResult(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.instances = []
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.instances.append(instance)
    def getInstances(self):
        return self.instances




class A(object):
    result = GetResult(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = 0
    def getAll(self):
        print self.result.getInstances()




a1 = A()
a2 = A()
a3 = A()

print a2.result.getInstances()
>> [<__main__.A object at 0x02302DF0>, <__main__.A object at 0x02302E10>, <__main__.Aobject at 0x02302E30>]
```

Comment: Could you illustrate your question with some code, for example code that works but that you consider less than ideal.

Comment: No. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Unless you're going to stick the same descriptor object on multiple classes, you should be fine just putting the instance list on the class instead of the descriptor.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to have a single list for all objects with a `GetResult` descriptor, even if they use different instances of `GetResult`, you probably want to stick the instance list onto the `GetResult` class. You could try using a class decorator or a metaclass to add the necessary logic to `__init__`, and probably also to add the descriptor if you do that.

Comment: Yes the same principle Bruno noted in the response below, I think I might just adopt to that instead actually if there are no other ideas.

Comment: The title of your question is wrong and should be something along the line of "How do I get a list of all instances of a class that makes use of a certain descriptor object?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's all your descriptor do, it's a bit of an abuse of the descriptor protocol. Just overriding your class `__new__` or `__init__` would be simpler:

```
class Foo(object):
    _instances = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        cls._instances.append(instance)
        return instance

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        return self._instances
```

Comment: The above is not an abuse in any way, it's kind of canonical by now. Now you can as well use a combination of the above and a simplified version of your descriptor relying on the host class to provide the instances list.

Comment: Yes I realized what you meant just now that's why I deleted my message, this is a nice approach, although I was planning on extending my descriptor with more functionality other then plain keeping references.

Comment: It would serve a purpose of a so to say, object lookup manager I guess.

Comment: Would that be an abuse of the protocol as well if I used it in that way?

Comment: To me keeping track of the class instances really doesn't belong to the descriptor - partly because it's not really what descriptors are for but well, I wouldn't be dogmatic about i, but mostly, the problem you describe : it's not transparent and needs some cooperation from the class, one way or another. So better to clearly aknowledge this and provide another way (decorator, class decorator, base class, metaclass, whatever) to provide the instances tracking part. Note that this "other way" could _also_ take care of adding the descriptor to the class...

Comment: Also, you cannot reference self from within __new__

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I am a bit newbie perhaps but if we are storing the instances in the classes meta class, we would need to call Foo._instances.append(instance) maybe? And then getting would be a matter of doing Foo._instances

Comment: `self` is nothing magic, it's just a name. `__new__` is called with the class, but it _does_ access the instance obviously since it's in charge of creating it <g>

Comment: oh then, perhaps we should do: cls._instances.append(instance) because self is not defined in our __new__ def

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43925/discussion-between-bojan-jovanovic-and-bruno-desthuilliers)

Comment: fixed exemple code - should have been `cls._instances.append(instance)` of course

Comment: Wouldn't it be technically more correct to pass all arguments on to `object.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)` so they can in turn can be passed to the class' `__init__()` method (assuming it has one or one is added later)?

Comment: @martineau: they still get passed to `__init__`

Comment: Unfortunately this is causing a memory leak in my application, do you have by chance any idea how to prevent it from constantly filling up the _instaces list on each request?

Comment: @BojanJovanovic : please open a new question with your current code and a bit more infos on the execution context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799047/memory-leak-in-django-when-keeping-a-reference-of-all-instances-of-forms