# Memory leak in django when keeping a reference of all instances of forms

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, metaprogramming

This is a followup to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784474/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-all-classes-implementing-descriptor-object-in-python/20784934?noredirect=1#comment31181082_20784934).

I have implemented the method for keeping a reference to all my forms in a array like mentioned by the selected answer in this but unfortunately I am getting a memory leak on each request to the django host.

The code in question is as follows:

This is my custom form I am extending which has a function to keep reference of neighboring forms, and whenever I instantiate a new form, it just keeps getting added to the _instances stack.

```
class StepForm(ModelForm):
    TAGS = []
    _instances = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = object.__new__(cls)
        cls._instances.append(instance)
        return instance
```

Even though this more of a python issue then Django I have decided that it's better to show you the full context that I am encountering this problem at.

As requested I am posting what I am trying to accomplish with this feat:

I have a js applet with steps, and for each step there is a form, but in order to load the contents of each step dynamically through JS I need to execute some calls on the next form in line. And on the previous aswell. Therefore the only solution I Could come up with is to just keep a reference to all forms on each request and just use the forms functions I need.

Comment: How did you verify there is memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's not only a Python issue - the execution context (here a Django app) is important too. As Ludwik Trammer rightly comments, you're in a long running process, and as such anything at the module or class level will live for the duration of the process. Also if using more than one process to serve the app you may (and will) get inconsistant results from one request to another, since two subsequent requests from a same user can (and will) end up being served by different processes.

To make a long story short: the way to safely keep per-user persistant state in a web application is to use sessions. Please explain what problem you're trying to solve, there's very probably a more appropriate (and possibly existing and tested) solution.

EDIT : ok what you're looking for is a "wizard". There are a couple available implementations for Django but most of them don't handle going back - which, from experience, can get tricky when each step depends on the previous one (and that's one of the driving points for using a wizard). What one usually do is have a `Wizard' class (plain old Python object) with a set of forms.

The wizard takes care of

1. step to step navigation
2. instanciating forms
3. maintaining state (which includes storing and retrieving form's data for each step, revalidating etc).

FWIW I've had rather mixed success using Django's existing session-based wizard. We rolled our own for another project (with somehow complex requirements) and while it works I wouldn't name it a success neither. Having ajax and file uploads thrown in the mix doesn't help neither. Anyway, you can try to start with an existing implementation, see how it fits your needs, and go for a custom solution if it doesn't - generic solutions sometimes make things harder than they have to be.

My 2 cents...

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply again Bruno. I have a js applet with steps, and for each step there is a form, but in order to load the contents of each step dynamically through JS I need to execute some calls on the next form in line. And on the previous aswell. Therefore the only solution I Could come up with is to just keep a reference to all forms on each request and just use the forms functions I need.

Comment: As Bruno says, sessions are the correct way to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok, I understood the issue I shall fix this with sessions. Thank you kindly for your help

Answer (score 1):

The leak is not just a *side effect* of your code - it's part of its *core function*. It is not possible to remove the leak without changing what the code does.

It does *exactly* what it is programmed to do - **every** time the form is displayed a new instance is created and added to the `_instances` list. It is never removed from the list. As a consequence after 100 requests you will have a list with 100 requests, after 1 000 requests there will be 1 000 instances in the list, and so on - until all memory is exhausted and the program crashes.

What did you want to accomplish by keeping all instances of your form? And what else did you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes I understand, I just wanted to keep a reference for the forms for each session request so that I can easily find the next form

Comment: I have declared in the main question what I was trying to accomplish so there might be a easier way to solve it.