# How can I keep track of object instances in a list with python without using constructors (__init__)?

Tags: python, oop

I want to keep track of object instances of a given class/subclasses in Python given my particular framework I cannot use constructors. As an alternative I could use either decorators or Singletons objects.

Are there any other alternatives except using global variables ?

Comment: A) Why can't you use constructors? B) What does a constructor have to do with keeping track of an object's instances? C) What have you tried anyway?

Comment: A) I am using Python within a proprietary framework which prevents me from using __init__.
B) I could populate a class attribute from the constructor to keep track of the instances.
C) decorators (looks like the best aproach so far) , Singletons (not a fan), Wondering if there are any other ways. 
oh and thanks for the -1

Comment: I'm assuming that you can't use `__new__` or `__metaclass__` either? Also, I didn't give you the downvote, but you should include that information in your original question.

Comment: I would be very curious to know which "proprietary framework" in Python prevents such thing, and then how does it??

Comment: Joel: correct for __new__.

Comment: Have you heard of GS secdb (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392636/slang-goldman-sachs-proprietary-programming-language) ? Imagine something similar where Python is the implemntation language.

Comment: In essence a preprocessor run over the class definition which prevent us from declaring __init__ or else it breaks our frameworkfor a particular sub-classes.

Comment: Can you subclass from a class which **does** have an `__init__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). That is, it's an object that can and will keep track of what things are where with the caveat that it will only do so if you've assigned a value to do it. Here's an example:

```
 class RevealAccess(object):
   """
      A data descriptor that sets and returns values
      normally and prints a message logging their access.
   """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
      self.val = initval
      self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      print 'Retrieving', self.name
      return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
      print 'Updating', self.name
      self.val = val
```

This is taken out from the documentation. However, add the following from [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784474/how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-all-classes-implementing-descriptor-object-in-python):

```
    _instances = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
      instance = object.__new__(cls)
      cls._instances.append(instance)
      return instance

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
      return self._instances
```

and you've achieved your goals:

```
  class Foo(object):
    desc = MyDesc('yo')

  foo = Foo()
  Foo.get_instances().length
```